# Font size shortcut in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to create a shortcut for changing the font size in the Visual Studio editor for all documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to do some thing like this in the past but could not find a way to make a shortcut to one of the Options menu items.  The next best thing I found was to use the [Quick Launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh417697.aspx)  tool to get to the menu item more quickly.  Not sure if that helps in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following single line command in [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) and assign a shortcut to it:

```
DTE.Properties("FontsAndColors", "TextEditor").Item("FontSize").Value = 20
```